# Get data from multiple tables based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, count, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I need to get some data from 3 different mysql tables as follows.

```
 +-----------------------------------+      
 | Questions                         |      
 -------------------------------------      
 | id: int(8)                        |      
 | -- data we don't care about here  |      
 | question: TEXT                    |      
 +-----------------------------------+    

 +--------------------------+               
 |Answers                   |               
 +--------------------------+               
 | id: int(8)               |               
 | -- other data            |               
 | answer: TEXT             |               
 +--------------------------+    

 +-----------------------------------+      
 |Votes                              |      
 +-----------------------------------+      
 | id: int(8)                        |      
 | step: tinyint(1)                  |      
 | answerId: int(8)                  |      
 +-----------------------------------+
```

I need to get the answer with the most votes to each question and the amount of votes that answer has.

The best query I could come up with is:

```sql
SELECT question, answer, count(votes.id) votesCount FROM questions INNER JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.questionId INNER JOIN votes ON answers.id = votes.answerId;
```

however that's wrong as it always returns a single result with the first question, a random answer and the total amount of votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that your query is missing a `group by` clause. So it returns just one row, with the overal count votes and an abitrary chosen question and answer.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, this is easily done with aggregatin and window fuctions:

```
select question, answer, votescount
from (
    select 
        q.question, 
        a.answer, 
        count(*) votescount,
        rank() over(partition by q.id order by count(*) desc) rn
    from questions q
    inner join answers a on q.id = a.questionid 
    inner join votes on a.id = v.answerid
    group by q.id, q.question, a.id, a.answer
) t
where rn = 1
```

In earlier versions, it is a bit more complicated. One option is to filter the aggregate resultset with a `having` clause that returns the top count per group:

```
select 
    q.question, 
    a.answer, 
    count(*) votescount,
    rank() over(partition by q.id order by count(*) desc) rn
from questions q
inner join answers a on q.id = a.questionid 
inner join votes on a.id = v.answerid
group by q.id, q.question, a.id, a.answer
having count(*) = (
    select count(*)
    from answers a1
    inner join votes v1 a1.id = v1.answerid
    where a1.questionid = q.id
    group by a1.id
    order by count(*) desc
    limit 1
)
```

Comment: I'm using the latest version of mysql so this works however there's an issue, if two answers to a question have the same amount of votes two results get returned instead of just 1

Comment: @thelmuxkriovar: yes, that's what `rank()` does. Which answer do you want if there are ties?

Comment: the one with the lowest id

Comment: @thelmuxkriovar: ok, so `row_number() over(partition by q.id order by count(*) desc, a.id)` (we could use `rank()` just the same, but `row_number()` makes it explicit we don't want ties).

Comment: that works! thanks a lot, can you please edit your answer to include that?